# How to make some windows play sound through the HDMI output and others use the laptop output

Tags: 20.04, sound, hdmi

I have my PC connected to my TV through HDMI, I can only play sounds through the TV or the PC. Is there a way to make some windows play through the TV and the rest through the PC? So if I play a movie on the TV I can still use my PC at the same time without the movie sounding on the headphones. Do i need to meet certain hardware specifications?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through pavucontrol

first install it:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

After launching it, go to Configuration Tab, You should see both your sound cards, HDMI and built-in (or something similar).

[image: PavuControl Configuration Tab]
(Mine was unplugged but ignore that)

Then Play the videos and go to Playback tab. You should see multiple applications, route each one to the sound card you want.

[image: pavucontrol choosing stream]

Comment: It only shows built in, does that mean I would need another sound card?

Comment: @SamuelAdipGonzalezAcharya I don't know, but do you get one card from the following commands? `cat /proc/asound/cards` and `aplay -l`?

If so, I _guess_ you need another card. Maybe there is another way

Comment: Yeah, it only shows one, I'll keep looking if there's another way. Thank you for helping me :)